# SQL query to display IBM Sterling B2B Integrator BPs configuration with the meaning of each PERSISTENCE_LEVEL

Tags: ibm-sterling

SQL query to display IBM Sterling B2B Integrator BPs configuration with the meaning of each PERSISTENCE_LEVEL.
The PERSISTENCE LEVEL is coded in the WFD (workflow definition) table.

```
select name, wfd.EXECNODE, wfd.PRIORITY QUEUE, wfd.LIFE_SPAN, 
wfd.PERSISTENCE_LEVEL PERSISTENCE_LEVEL_ID,

CASE PERSISTENCE_LEVEL

when 0 then 'SystemDefault'

when 1 then 'Full'

when 3 then 'StepStatusEMO'

when 4 then 'StartStopEMO'

when 5 then 'StepStatusOnly'

when 8 then 'StartStop'

when 9 then 'Zero'

when 10 then 'ErrorOnly'

else ''||persistence_level

END PERSISTENCE_LEVEL

from WFD wfd, wfd_versions wfdv

where wfd.WFD_ID=wfdv.WFD_ID and wfd.wfd_version = wfdv.WFD_VERSION

and wfd.WFD_VERSION=wfdv.DEFAULT_VERSION;
```

[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXIqD.png)